# jQuery .each() AJAX

Tags: jquery

The loop works. But the updating of the title does not. The alert that is commented out does show that the data is correct.

```
<script>
    var usercount = 0;
    var nbw = '';
    var _$this = '';
    $('.alphabet').each(function () {
        _$this = $(this);
        nbw = $(this).val();
        $.ajax({
            type: "Get",
            url: "cfc/basic.cfc?method=CountUsersByLetter&returnformat=json",
            data: "nbw=" + nbw,
            datatype: "html",
            success: function (response) {
                usercount = parseInt(response.substring(0, 10));
                //$(_$this.target).attr('title', usercount);
            },
            error: function (xhr, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                alert('errorThrown');
            }
        });
        $(_$this.target).attr('title', usercount);
        //alert(nbw + ' usercount=' + usercount);
    });
</script>
```

Comment: You're firing (presumably) 26 HTTP requests at once? That doesn't sound like a good idea.

Comment: `$(_$this.target)` is wrong. `_$this` is `$(this)` and $(this) has no `target`. There is just `event.target`. However I think you should change it too this: `_$this.attr('title', usercount);`

Comment: I could return a query with counts by letter. I'm just not adept at handling the json return yet.

Comment: I'm try to post my new code for handling a returned query with all counts by letter but it is more characters than allowed in a comment.  How the heck do I post the code?

Comment: Did you try my updated answer?

Comment: {"COLUMNS":["PAGESNUM","LETTER"],"DATA":[["372","A"],["922","B"],["779","C"],["378","D"],["132","E"],["353","F"],["551","G"],["591","H"],["6","I"],["340","J"],["261","K"],["314","l"],["837","M"],["88","N"],["120","O"],["303","P"],["14","Q"],["355","R"],["762","S"],["235","T"],["12","U"],["44","V"],["581","W"],["49","Y"],["19","Z"]]}<!-- " ---></TD></TD></TD></TH></TH></TH></TR></TR></TR></TABLE></TABLE></TABLE></A>

Comment: This is the better solution.  I need to work out the handling of the response.

Comment: I think you should open a new thread for your current problem...

Answer (score 1):

`Ajax` is **asynchronous** which means the data will return at an arbitrary time in the future

You have to use the data you got from the server inside the callbacks.

**The code(with several fixes):**

```
<script>
$('.alphabet').each(function () {
    var $this = $(this);
    var nbw = $this.val();
    var usercount = 0;
    $.ajax({
        type: "Get",
        url: "cfc/basic.cfc?method=CountUsersByLetter&returnformat=json",
        data: "nbw=" + nbw,
        datatype: "html",
        success: function (response) {
            usercount = parseInt(response.substring(0, 10));
            $this.attr('title', usercount);
        },
        error: function (xhr, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            alert('errorThrown');
        }
    });
});
</script>
```

Comment: +1. This seems like the most reasonable answer. The question is, why did the OP comment this same logic out.

Comment: I put it back the way it was (un-commented the line inside the success callback). Same results.

Comment: @user990016. What is `$(this).target`?? maybe it should be `$(this)`

Comment: @user990016. Please try it now, I changed the weird `this.target`

Comment: The ressulting title is "NaN".